# Unable to run puppet-client on the machine

Tags: puppet

Manually running the puppet code shows the below error

```
/etc/puppet/environments/cipher/modules/profile/manifests/base.pp:2 on node cipheronic.comKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEggEAfNuo1InLxAG4myDkOTFk1wqJfr7qX7VB2gEA
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

What is going wrong ?

Comment: Is your node `cipheronic.comKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEggEAfNuo1InLxAG4myDkOTFk1wqJfr7qX7VB2gEA` defined ?

Comment: What's "puppet-client"?  Do you mean `puppet agent`?

Comment: In any event, the error message appears to be implicating a problem in one of your manifests.  We probably will need a [mre] to diagnose the issue, and we will *certainly* need more information than we have now, starting with at least the first few lines of your manifest for `profile::base`.

Comment: This error message, as it is probably a copy-paste from either a `puppet apply` (or `puppet agent -t`) or directly from Puppet Console UI, means you have an issue with your code at `/etc/puppet/environments/cipher/modules/profile/manifests/base.pp`, line `2`.

_If you can paste here your code (`base.pp`, maybe we can help more)_

The message generated by the resource at that specific line should give you some hint.

**UPDATE:** moved as comment as [@john-bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger) suggests